# What is $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}(\left \lfloor{-\dfrac{1}{x}}\right \rfloor )$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-explanation

> What is $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}(\left \lfloor{-\dfrac{1}{x}}\right \rfloor )$?

Why is it not -1? Book says 1.

Comment: $-1$ is the greatest integer less than $-\frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $x\to+\infty$, $-\frac1x$ approaches $0$ from the *negative* side; it is negative for any sufficiently large finite $x$. Thus we must conclude that the limit of its floor is $-1$, this being the floor of an arbitrarily small (in magnitude) negative number.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \lfloor -\frac{1}{x} \rfloor $$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (-\frac{1}{x}-\{-\frac{1}{x}\})$$
$$=0-1=-1$$

Comment: Yes got error in typing.

Comment: Why is $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left\{-\frac1x\right\}$$ any easier to calculate than the original limit? This answer is not useful, it just transforms the original problem to one equally difficult, and then assumes we know the answer to it.

Comment: Then we can go by definition of greatest integer function like if $n\le x \lt (n+1) \,\,,where n\in I $ then $[x]=n$ , and $-\frac{1}{x} \rightarrow 0^{-}$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ hence answer will be $-1$

Comment: But you don't need the "fractional part" function to do that.

Comment: Yes not in the above approach but given solution is using the same .